# Undefined offset Error while uploading CSV File with Blank Cells at Top

Tags: php, mysql, csv

This is my CSV File:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_1cAszh75fYTjdobFMwVFdVT2c

This is my code to upload the CSV File and insert data to my mysql table:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  

  $ddates = $_POST['uploaddate'];

  if($_FILES['file']['name'])  
  {  
       $filename = explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);  
       if($filename[1] == 'csv')  
       {  
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");  
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle))  
            {                 
                 $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);  
                 $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);  
                 $item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[2]);  
                 $item4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[3]);  
                 $item5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[4]);  
                 $item6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[5]);  
                 $item7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[5]);  
                 $item8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[6]);  
                 $item9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[6]);  
                 $item10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[7]);  
                 $item11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[7]);  
                 $item12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[8]);  
                 $item13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[9]);  
                 $item14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[10]);  
                 $item15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[11]);  
                 $item16 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[12]);  




                 $sql="INSERT into tblone(uploaddate, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen) values('$ddates', '$item1','$item2','$item3','$item4','$item5','$item6','$item7','$item8','$item9','$item10','$item11','$item12','$item13','$item14','$item15','$item16')";  
                 mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
            }  
            fclose($handle);  
            print "Import done";  
       }  
  }  
 }
```

When I try to upload the CSV File it shows Error "Notice: Undefined offset........:"

[image]

I know why it shows the error. As you can see, my csv file has 9 columns with column header at top. But the next 4 columns do not have any header. I mean "Debit Amount" "Credit Amount" etc do not have values/headlines at top of those columns.

My code works fine as per as uploading CSV file and inserting data to mysql table is concerned. But the error doesn't look good in the eye.

I want the codes to be executed without showing any error.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this code on top of you phpfile
`error_reporting(0);`

or validate first by using isset example code:

`$data1 = (isset($data[0])) ? $data[0] : '';`

so on and so forth then send the values here

`$item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data1);`

Comment: Excellent! This helps. Thanks a lot.